# Open external browser in webview?

Tags: java, android, webview

I am trying to run twitter in webview, but whenever i try to catch external link to open some default browser nothing happens, it's like app has stalled.

Example:- If i click on some blog link inside twitter webview, nothing happens.

I have tried this,

```
 private class InsideWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView View, String url) {
        if( url.startsWith("https://mobile.twitter.com") || url.startsWith("https://m.twitter.com") ) {
            MoviesFragment.this.progress.setProgress(0);
            View.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity( intent );
        return true;
    }


}
```

but nothing happens, when i try to capture log, there is nothing about webview in it please help.

**UPDATE**

*This time i took a different approach, but still the same result.*

This time i created a context menu to catch HTML link and then divert them to external browser, but this time also in twitter nothing happens. A popup appears to `open in browser` after clicking it nothing happens.

```
 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    WebView w = (WebView)v;
    WebView.HitTestResult result = w.getHitTestResult();
    if(result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE) {
        menu.addSubMenu(0, 0, 0, "open in browser");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
 if (item.getTitle()=="open in browser") {//open the actual page into using the browser
        myWebView.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(myWebView.getUrl())));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

The problem was String URL was catching the new URL, that's why only home page was opening after triggering `open in browser`.

Implemented `HitTestResult` and then it was a piece of cake.

```
private String url = "";




 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.........................................
.......................................
............................
}


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
{
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    WebView w = (WebView)v;
    WebView.HitTestResult result = w.getHitTestResult();


    if(result.getType() == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_ANCHOR_TYPE)
    {
        menu.addSubMenu(4, 4, 4, "Open in browser");
        url = result.getExtra();

    }

}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    if (item.getTitle()=="Open in browser"){

        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(browserIntent);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I hope someone will find it useful.